# Python type seeming to change

Tags: python-2.7

Var type seems to change when calling it later in for loop.

I haven't tried anything else because what I see simply doesn't make sense.

```py
import sys

rtt = 1.012
tmp = []
if type(rtt) is float:
    print("Float detected")
    tmp.append('{0:.4g}'.format(rtt))
elif type(rtt) is str and rtt == 'timeout':
    print("String detected and value = timeout")
    tmp.append(rtt)
else:
    pass

ssum = []
for n in range(len(tmp)):
    if type(tmp[n]) is float:
        print("Float detected")
        ssum.append(tmp[n])
    elif type(tmp[n]) is str:
        print("String detected with a value of {0}".format(tmp[n]))
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('An error occured when trying to identify type and value of results, process is exiting!')
        sys.exit()

<OUTPUT>
$python test.py
Float detected
String detected with a value of 1.012
$
```

I would expect the var type to be the same as when I appended it to the list but when I iterate over the list, it says the type is a string.

Any ideas why this is happening and why my expectations seem to be flat wrong?

Comment: `tmp.append('{0:.4g}'.format(rtt))` is appending a string version of your float value.

Comment: thank you for catching that. I was previously printing here where the append statement is and didn't see it when I made the change.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

`'{0:.4g}'.format(rtt)`

You are formatting the float value `rtt` into a string

Answer (score 0):

tmp.append('{0:.4g}'.format(rtt)) is appending a string version of your float value. – jasonharper

Thanks to Jason for the answer